# javascript and jquery functions are not working/exexcuting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

While inspecting the elements it gives 304 code.and after hitting Ctrl+shift+r
reposnse code is 200.but still it's not working..

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#viewCRM").hide();
    $("#viewSearch").hide();
    $("#viewCamp").hide();
    $("#viewSearchTable").hide();
});
$(function() {

    $(".home").click(function() {
        alert("Opening CRM");
        $("#viewCRM").slideToggle();
        $("#viewSearch").hide();
        $("#viewCamp").hide();
        $("#viewSearchTable").hide();
    });
    $("#camp").click(function() {
        alert("Opening Campaign");
        $("#viewCamp").slideToggle();   
        $("#viewCRM").hide();
        $("#viewSearch").hide();
        $("#viewSearchTable").hide();
    });
    $("#search").click(function() {
        alert("Opening Search");
        $("#viewSearch").slideToggle();
        $("#viewCRM").hide();
        $("#viewCamp").hide();
        $("#viewSearchTable").Toggle();
    });
    $("#littleMerit").click(function() {
        $("#viewCamp").hide();
        $("#viewCRM").slideToggle();

    });
</script>
```

Why is my code not working?

Comment: You have not closed `$(function() {`

Comment: this is a JSP page and running on tomcat server

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: thanks nikhil, i was trying it for most 3 hours, and missing tiny braces,
Now i am looking like a fool.
Thank you..

Comment: @mohitsharma - Not a problem. Great it worked.

Comment: Okay that's closes the question with a simple typo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of your script needs a closing `});` for the `$(function () {`. Working code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">    
  $(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#viewCRM").hide();
    $("#viewSearch").hide();
    $("#viewCamp").hide();
    $("#viewSearchTable").hide();
  });
  $(function() {
    $(".home").click(function() {
      alert("Opening CRM");
      $("#viewCRM").slideToggle();
      $("#viewSearch").hide();
      $("#viewCamp").hide();
      $("#viewSearchTable").hide();
    });
    $("#camp").click(function() {
      alert("Opening Campaign");
      $("#viewCamp").slideToggle();   
      $("#viewCRM").hide();
      $("#viewSearch").hide();
      $("#viewSearchTable").hide();
    });
    $("#search").click(function() {
      alert("Opening Search");
      $("#viewSearch").slideToggle();
      $("#viewCRM").hide();
      $("#viewCamp").hide();
      $("#viewSearchTable").Toggle();
    });
    $("#littleMerit").click(function() {
      $("#viewCamp").hide();
      $("#viewCRM").slideToggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

And noticing your code, there are few things:

- `.Toggle()` doesn't look like a jQuery function. Are you trying to use `.toggle()`?

Comment: Thanks praveen working it's working.

Comment: @mohitsharma What's the use of `.Toggle()`?

Comment: I am using toggle to show a specific <div> ,user can click on button and can see/user different functionality on the same page/screen

Comment: can you share a short example of Sending ajax request to servlet with search parameter And getting an List<Obj> from Servlet and displaying it to jsp page using ajax.
If you want i can also metion my existing code.

Comment: You cannot use AJAX to transport / communicate Java Objects. Sorry. Only thing is possible are JavaScript objects and not Java. `:(`

Comment: I am currently sending Ajax request to my servlet, Servlet is using getAlldata(DAO model) and getting a list<data>, then i am using GSON to parse list<data> to jsonElement THEN i am printing json object.
I am able to do it  for Single Obj but not able to print  List<Obj> ...

Comment: Try asking the servlet to send a JSON based output of the list. If you are using JSP then you can catch the Java Object using Sessions or something. But even then you have issues.